# VC dimension of indicator functions is equal to pseudo dimension

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, machine-learning, dimension-theory-algebra

I am reading the "Foundation of machine learning" by Mehryar Mohri ([https://cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlbook/](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Emohri/mlbook/)). In the proof of Theorem 11.8, it said the following statement, which I can not understand.

Let $H$ be a family of real-valued functions, and
\begin{align}
G=\{ (x,y)\rightarrow L(h(x),y):h\in H\}.
\end{align}
Then, we define the another family of function
\begin{align}
C=\{c(h,t):(x,y)\rightarrow 1_{L(h(x),y)>t} ,h\in H, t\ge 0 \}.
\end{align}

Then, the author said that the VC dimension of $C$ is equal to the pseudo dimension of $G$.

How can we prove this?

---

To show the VC dimension of $C$, we have to find such $\{(x_1,y_1), \ldots,(x_d,y_d) \}$ satisfying the following: for any binary vector $\mathbf{b}\in \{0,1\}^d $, there exists $(h,t)$ such that
\begin{align}
c(h,t)(x_i,y_i) = 1_{h(x_i)-y_i>t}=b_i, \forall i
\end{align}
Note that in the definition above, **$t$ is equal for all $i$, but changes over the selection of $h$**.

However, in the definition in (11.3) of the book, we know that the $Pdim(G)$ is equivalent to the modified VC dimension given by the following. There exist $\{(x_1,y_1,t_1), \ldots,(x_d,y_d, t_d) \}$, for any binary vector $\mathbf{b}\in \{0,1\}^d $, there exists $h$ such that
\begin{align}
 1_{h(x_i)-y_i>t_i}=b_i, \forall i
\end{align}
Note that in the definition above, **the $t$ is different for all $i$, but fixed for the selction of $h$**.

Comment: Thm. 11.8 says that $L \ge 0$. Given that this is just the definition of pseudo-dimension (see Def.s 11.4,11.5, and specifically equation 11.3). Indeed, the only special thing beyond (11.3) is that $t \ge 0$ is specified, but since $\{L < 0\} = \varnothing$ always, no shattering set will have a $t_i < 0$.

Comment: The main different is  $t$ in the definitions. To be more clear, I have added some details in the question.

Comment: FYI:  the tag [tag:dimension-theory-analysis] is really meant for questions which deal with topological and metric notions of dimension (i.e. notions of fractal dimension).  This question really doesn't fit into that tag.  It is possible that the question here is more closely related to algebraic notions of dimension (see [tag:dimension-theory-algebra]), but these are notions which are largely foreign to me, so I don't know if that tag would be appropriate or not.

Comment: Ah, you're quite right. But nevertheless, the VC dimension of the resulting hypothesis class is bounded by the pseudo dimension of ${G}$ (if you can shatter with a constant $t$, then you can shatter with variable $t$, but the converse isn't true), so the result still follows (but seems needlessly loose). Also note that if $\forall t, \exists \tau: \{L > t\} = \{ |h(x) - y| > \tau\},$ (reasonable for regression losses), then the pseudo-dimension of $H$ would be relevant (with $t_i = y_i + \tau$ and $t_i = y_i - \tau$). Nevertheless, as written, you're correct in questioning this statement.

Comment: @stochasticboy321, how can we strictly show that $VCdim(C)\le Pdim(G)$?